What does "Embed, don't Stack" mean?
In Production Haskell, Matt Parsons has a section titled "Embed, don't Stack". In it he mentions things like:

It is a mistake to add a ton of monad transformers in your application type. One monad transformer for every effect you might care about.


The general pattern that is recommended is to embed things into your App type.


Factoring your code such that effects are run independently of each other makes for a simpler time to understand and read the code.

But he never clearly defines what he means by embed.

Is there a common definition for this term?
What does embedding look like in practice?


The author appears to argue that instead of stacking monad transformers to get the features you want, you should directly implement the relevant typeclasses.
For example, if you'd like state management, instead of changing type App s a = ReaderT (Env s) IO a into type App s a = StateT s (ReaderT (Env s) IO) a, you embed state into your own type by defining an instance of MonadState for App s a.
With the transformer, your own and users' code can easily lock you into your specific stack due to type dependencies and lifts, making it harder to add other types without breaking APIs and refactoring.
By implementing MonadState, the type remains the same and the fact that you support State is just an independent dozen lines that don't leak into the rest of the program. If you ever update your underlying type, you only ever have to update the instance.
They go on to say you should similarly be careful about interleaving execution as one might with transformer stacks, because this can end up making promises you can't keep.
Their example is preferring two independent runRedis :: Redis a -> App a and runSql :: Database a -> App a, because these are independent and easily written and understood.
If you instead stack with a liftRedis :: Redis a -> Database a, then it's hard to predict what will happen to already executed Redis changes if the SQL database ends up rolling back the transaction.

I haven't read the book, but from just the snippet you pasted it sounds to me like the author is saying that
type App a = FooT (BarT (BazT IO a))

is not a good idea because it means that any function returning App a can perform any number of four different effects: it might do Foo, or Bar, or Baz, or IO, or all of them. Instead, have a much smaller App type, with maybe one or two really core effects baked into it, like
type App a = Reader (Config, DbHandle) a

Then the functions that need to use some other effects can surface those effects in the a part:
debitAccountBy :: AccountNumber -> Money -> App (WriteToDb Money)

This way you can use the type system to separate your program into more- and less-effectful sections, instead of having all your functions capable of performing every kind of effect.
Or perhaps a similarly flexible construction like
type App effs a = effs (Reader (Config, DbHandle)) a

is intended.
